# SQL SELECT and GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
JOIN tags
 ON tags.did = posts.did
JOIN users
 ON users.username = posts.username
GROUP by tags.did
```

Now the result only shows one tag when I have two tags for the `did`. I want it to show all the tags I have for it kinda like this

```
a post | tag 1, tag 2
```

but right now, it's showing it like this

```
a post | tag 1
```

And I don't know why it won't show the other tag. I hope this is enough relevant information. (Pardon me, I'm a bit of a SQL beginner right now)

Comment: you need to look at using the `group_concat` aggregate function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat this will create a list of your tags per post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY (essential part, not tested )

```
SELECT p.postid, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tags)
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.did = p.did
INNER JOIN users u ON u.username = p.username
GROUP by t.did
```

Comment: The previous code you posted worked, so I'm gonna go ahead accept this  as the answer, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode

```
SELECT post.Text, Coalesce('',select tag +',' from tags where tags.did=posts.did)
FROM posts
```

or us Group_concat
[group concat](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Language) As Languages FROM CountryLanguage WHERE CountryCode = 'THA'
```

I dont have a mysql to test against but you need something like this.[My Sql Coalsce](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php)